# while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) its not executed and not entered in loop?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am creating Address book. its save group name in sqlite. but its not working. its not entering in loop.?  please check my code. what is the problem in my code?

```
-(void) selectGroup
{
ssArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSString *selectStmt=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select GroupName from AddGroup;"];

NSLog(@"the selet statement is :%@",selectStmt);

const char *cSelectStmt=[selectStmt UTF8String];

sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, cSelectStmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {

    const unsigned char *cName = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);

    NSString *name=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)cName];

    [self.ssArray addObject:name];
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);

NSLog(@"Array from database is  :%@",ssArray);
}
```

Comment: You *must* check the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`.

Comment: i was modify that line  == SQLITE_OK bro. but while loop not executed

Comment: And what is the return value of `sqlite3_step()`?

Comment: This function cannot return zero.